# date format and elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to store unixtimestamp as a value to a field in Elasticsearch Index. The version I am using is 1.7.3.
While indexing the data mapping for the field is :-

```
             {"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}
```

the data is stored properly but when I try to query the particular field for date value I get parse exception.
query used is :-

```
             {"query":{"term":{"contentPublishedTime":1447764265}}}
```

Error prompted :-

```
             IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "1447764265" is malformed at "5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your date format. Please find available ones here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

`dateOptionalTime` has this format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`. This doesn't look like what you're passing at all.

So what you have to do is, either to pass date in this format or have another field, which would store your data in format, that you're running your queries against. It's probably going to be `epoch_millis` or `epoch_second`

Comment: I have tried using epoch_millis format but this doesn't work. Also would like to point out that same query with same mapping works well in ElasticSearch v1.3 and lower version. I have read the doc. for v1.7 but didn't find any change related to format. Am I missing something in this regard ?????

Comment: Can't say I know. You have to go through changelog from 1.3 to 1.7 and look for changes done.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the 1.7 docs. Looks like epoch_* are not yet supported there:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-date-format.html